Notion of Kahler differentials for Berkovic spaces
What is, in abstract analytic geometry (I mean, for example, in Berkovic spaces), the approach used for differential forms?
Ordinary Kahler differentials from commutative algebra/algebraic geometry don't work well: as an example, $d(sin(z)=cos(z)dz)$ if seen as ordinary smooth/holomorphic differential forms but they are not the same element in the module $\Omega_{{O}_\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{C}}$ of Kahler differentials of the complex algebra of holomorphic functions.
To obtain a correct notion, we would need at least to quotient out by this kinds of relations.
Is there any resource on the internet explaining it?

There is one in condensed mathematics. See Clausen–Scholze's Condensed Mathematics and Complex Geometry. In particular, in Lecture 13, they discuss (purely "algebraic" definition of) holomorphic differential forms.

I do not know for Berkovic spaces, but for complex manifolds/spaces the ordinary Kähler differentials are also already bad as you mentioned. However, the universally finite Kähler differentials are well-behaved holomorphic/analytic differential forms on complex manifolds/spaces (including singular spaces). Universally finite Kähler differentials are defined in Kunz - "Kähler differentials". Appealing to condensed mathematics seems overkill - but I really am not an expert.

@ThomasKurbach I can't find any public source on the internet about that. Could you write their definition here?

@user720386 Kähler differentials $\Omega_R$ can be defined as a module representing the derivation functor, i.e. $\mathrm{Der}(R,M)\cong \mathrm{Hom}(\Omega_R,M)$ for every module $M$. Universally finite Kähler differentials are defined the same way, except that $\Omega_R$ should be finitely generated and the previous isomorphism only holds for finitely generated modules $M$. While Kähler differentials always exist, universally finite differentials may not always exist. At least in complex geometry (with singularities) they exist and are well-behaved.
